# add an array of linked document _ids to couchdb documents in python

Tags: python, dictionary, couchdb, relationship

I want to add a `links` property to each couchdb document based on data in a csv file.
the value of the links property is to be an array of dicts containing the couchdb `_id` of the linked document and the `linkType`

When I run the script i get a links error (see error info below)
I am not sure how to create the dict key `links` if it doesn't exist and add the link data, or otherwise append to the `links` array if it does exist.

an example of a document with the links will look like this:

```
{
    _id: p_3,
    name: 'Smurfette'
    links: [
                {to_id: p_2, linkType: 'knows'},
                {to_id: o_56, linkType: 'follows'}
           ]
}
```

python script for processing the csv file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

# Version 1
# 
# csv fields: ID,fromType,fromID,toType,toID,LinkType,Directional


import csv, sys, couchdb


def csv2couchLinks(database, csvfile):

    # CouchDB Database Connection etc
    server = couchdb.Server()
    #assumes that couchdb runs on http://localhost:5984
    db = server[database]
    #assumes that db is already created

    # CSV file
    data = csv.reader(open(csvfile, "rb")) # Read in the CSV file rb=read/binary
    csv_links= csv.DictReader(open(csvfile, "rb"))


    def makeLink(from_id, to_id, linkType):
        # get doc from db
        doc = db[from_id]

        # construct link object
        link = {'to_id':to_id, 'linkType':linkType}

        # add link reference to array at key 'links'
        if doc['links'] in doc:
            doc['links'].append(link)
        else:
            doc['links'] = [link]

        # update the record in the database
        db[doc.id] = doc


    # read each row in csv file
    for row in csv_links:

        # get entityTypes as lowercase and entityIDs
        fromType = row['fromType'].lower()
        fromID   = row['fromID']
        toType   = row['toType'].lower()
        toID     = row['toID']

        linkType = row['LinkType']

        # concatenate 'entity type' and 'id' to make couch '_id'
        fromIDcouch = fromType[0]+'_'+fromID #eg 'p_2' <= person 2
        toIDcouch = toType[0]+'_'+toID

        makeLink(fromIDcouch, toIDcouch, linkType)
        makeLink(toIDcouch, fromIDcouch, linkType)


# Run csv2couchLinks() if this is not an imported module
if __name__ == '__main__':
    DATABASE = sys.argv[1]
    CSVFILE = sys.argv[2]
    csv2couchLinks(DATABASE,CSVFILE)
```

error info:

```
$ python LINKS_csv2couchdb_v1.py "qmhonour" "./tablesAsCsv/links.csv"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LINKS_csv2couchdb_v1.py", line 65, in <module>
    csv2couchLinks(DATABASE,CSVFILE)   
  File "LINKS_csv2couchdb_v1.py", line 57, in csv2couchLinks
    makeLink(fromIDcouch, toIDcouch, linkType)
  File "LINKS_csv2couchdb_v1.py", line 33, in makeLink
    if doc['links'] in doc:
KeyError: 'links'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is condensing the `if` block to this:

```
doc.setdefault('links', []).append(link)
```

The dictionary's `setdefault` method checks to see if `links` exists in the dictionary, and if it doesn't, it creates a key and makes the value an empty list (the default). It then appends `link` to that list. If `links` does exist, it just appends `link` to the list.

```
def makeLink(from_id, to_id, linkType):
    # get doc from db
    doc = db[from_id]

    # construct link object
    link = {'to_id':to_id, 'linkType':linkType}

    # add link reference to array at key 'links'
    doc.setdefault('links', []).append(link)

    # update the record in the database
    db[doc.id] = doc
```

Comment: that works great! and I note that it is possible to do this for deeper nested structures where multiple levels may not exist. eg. `doc.setdefault('links', {}).setdefault(toType, []).append(link)` to give a structure like `{someKey:someValue, links: {someType:[link]}}`

Comment: Yep, you got it :) It's a pretty useful feature that will definitely cut some lines from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
if doc['links'] in doc:
```

With:

```
if 'links' in doc:
```